# C struct members not initialized to zero in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Could someone explain why I get this?

```
CGRect rect;
NSLog(@"rect is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
// rect is {{-1.99891, 2.58159e-38}, {1.91754e-41, 8.46552e-39}}
```

And what about primitives?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990817/objective-c-ints-always-initialized-to-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C initializes *instance* variables to 0.  It does not necessarily initialize *local* variables to 0.

If you have ARC enabled, Objective-C initializes local variables that are object pointers (e.g. `NSObject *`, `UIView *`, etc.) to nil.  But it doesn't initialize any other local variables.  Other local variables (and object pointers if ARC is disabled) will have random values unless you explicitly initialize them.